# pdo cassandra returns empty result

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra

I tried to create a program to get the contents of a table with cassandra-pdo but it returns an empty array, what is the problem? I think it does connect to cassandra since when I changed the port it gave me an error.

```
<?php 
$dsn = "cassandra:host=localhost;port=9160";
$db = new PDO($dsn);
$db->exec("USE kspace;");



$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Bite;");
//$stmt->bindValue(':key', 'data');
$stmt->execute();


var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
?>
```

I use cassandra 2.0 and cqlsh to create the keyspace and table.

This is the result:

```
array(0) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing :

```
*var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
?>*
```

with:

```
*$out = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($out);
?>*
```